# Entity framework: automatic deletion of parent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the following model classes:

```
 public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Text Subject { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Text Body { get; set; }
}

public class Text
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The model is simple - each Thing must reference to two Text entities. Each Text entry at any point in time should be referenced only by a single entity of any other type (Thing is not the only one).

Is it possible to configure EF5 to automatically delete all referenced Texts when Thing gets deleted (via `context.Set<Thing>().Remove`), or should it be done with a database trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to configure `CASCADE DELETE` at database level and don't have to do anything special at Entity framework level.